# Js spread operator and nested arrays

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux, spread-syntax

I have following object

```
state = {"line": [
   {"media": [1, 2, 3 ]},
   {"media": []},
   {"media": []},
]}
```

What I need is to remove element in media array.

I try the following

```
return {
            ...state, line: [{
                ...state.line[line_index], media = [
                        ...state.line[line_index].media.slice(0, action.payload.index),
                        ...state.line[line_index].media.slice(action.payload.index + 1)
                ]
            }]
        }
```

but it doesn't work, it replaces media with object.

I don't get how to do it correctly. Can some one please show the way and describe it please

Comment: Shouldn’t that be `media:` instead of `media =`?

Comment: no, this way it removes all objects besides modified one

Comment: what do you want to achieve? what is your actions payload looking like?

Comment: What I need is to remove element in media array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you forgot is reassembling the line array properly. Try breaking it down like this:

```
const changedElement = {
    ...state.line[lineIndex],
    media: [
        ...state.line[lineIndex].media.slice(0, action.payload.index),
        ...state.line[line_index].media.slice(action.payload.index + 1)
    ]
}

return {
    ...state,
    line: [
        ...state.line.slice(0, line_index),
        changedElement,
        ...state.line.slice(line_index + 1)
    ]
}
```

What you want to do is write the current structure of your state:

```
state = {
    line: [
        {
            media: []
        },
        {
            media: []
        }
    ]
}
```

What you can then do is making it generic and containing state. So, `state` should be a copy of `state` (by putting `...state` in it) and `line` should be a copy of `line`. The only difference between `line` and `state` is that it's an array. Making an immutable copy of an array is a bit more involved than making such a copy of an object. But in your code, you did this already for your `changedElement`.

For a further read on this, you should have a look at immutable update patterns, as these are just recipes you can always reuse: https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns

Comment: that works great, thank you very much. can you please be so kind and describe step by step, because for me it is pain each time when I have to deal with nested arrays and spread op.